# Novamente ou De novo?

Tags: gramática, sinônimos

A princípio as duas têm a mesma definição, mas:

Tem diferença entre usar um ou outro?

Um pode ser substituído pelo outro?

Em que casos não poderia substituir um pelo outro?

Comment: Acho que se podem usar as duas em qualquer contexto.

Answer (score 4):

Ambos são *sinônimos*;

No entanto **novamente** é um *advérbio* e **de novo** é uma *locução adverbial*, a *Norma Gramatical Portuguesa* reconhece sete grupos de advérbios:

- **de lugar**, **de tempo**, **de modo**, **de negação**, **de dúvida**, **de intensidade** e de **afirmação**.

## Advérbio

É a classe gramatical das palavras que modificam um verbo, um adjetivo ou um outro advérbio. Raramente modifica um substantivo. É a palavra invariável que indica as circunstâncias em que ocorre a ação verbal.

## Locução adverbial

Ocorre quando duas,três ou mais palavras exercem função de pronome e substantivo. São conjuntos de palavras, geralmente introduzidas por uma locução, que exercem a função de expressão.

### Tipos

- **de modo:** a custo; à pressa; à toa; à vontade; às avessas; às claras; às direitas; às escuras; ao acaso; a torto e a direito; ao contrário; a sós; de bom grado; de cor; de má vontade; em geral; em silêncio; em vão; etc.
- **de intensidade:** de muito; de pouco
- **de afirmação:** com certeza; com efeito; de facto; na verdade; sem dúvida, claro que sim, sempre, etc.
- **de negação:** de forma alguma; de maneira nenhuma; de modo algum
- **de dúvida:** quem sabe; ao acaso;se possível etc.
- **de meio ou instrumento:** cortar à faca (à faca); escrever à mão(à mão); andar a pé (a pé); viajar de avião (de avião); andar de bicicleta (de bicicleta).

Fonte:

- [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advérbio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adv%C3%A9rbio)
- [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locução_adverbial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_adverbial)

Comment: The latter part of the answer (after the first three words) doesn't really add much to this particular question. The question was not about classification (and you neglect to specify which classification applies here in any case...). I'd be more interested in geographic usage patterns (if there are any) or contexts in which one or the other is more common.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Frank. Although it's nice of you to have further detailed some related topics of the Portuguese grammar, they end up not adding that much to the answer and make it feel more like "tl;dr".

Comment: @Frank: It might be late to comment but, it may be useful for others in the future. The question was completely answered in the first paragraph "Ambos são sinônimos", then the author just detailed the answer. I just missed which "locução verbal" type "de novo" is owned.